# Qual ferramenta usar para converter para código um UML desenvolvido visualmente?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

Preciso de uma ferramenta/plugin do Eclipse que me permita desenvolver diagramas de classes, atividades e sequência em UML e que gere o código.

Costumo utilizar o Eclipse com plugin Omondo, mas parece que foi descontinuado. A última versão que consegui foi a Eclipse 2.1, deve ter uns 3 anos.

Comment: Apesar da pergunta fazer uma recomendação, está estabelecendo requisitos específicos. A pergunta não é ruim e não deveria ter sido fechada. ver mais em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-questoes-de-recomendacao. Votando para reabrir

Answer (score 4):

O [Eclipse Modeling Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/keplersr1) é uma distribuição do Eclipse feita especialmente para modelagem, que inclui UML 2.0. Apenas faça o download do pacote.

Answer (score 2):

A [OMONDO](http://www.ejb3.org/) continua distribuindo o EclipseUML para novas versões do Eclipse, infelizmente não há *trial* para essas produto, você precisará testar o EclipseUML com o Eclipse Galileo ou anterior (sinceramente eu não investiria em uma empresa com essas políticas, principalmente quando você considera o [preço](http://www.ejb3.org/pricing.html) praticado por eles).

Tratando-se de soluções integradas (e, nesse caso específico, proprietárias) eu recomendaria o  [Visual Paradigm UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/) - a versão comunitária infelizmente não é capaz de gerar código, mas você consegue um *trial* de uma versão comercial no site. A ferramenta é bem bacana, e considero o [preço](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/shop/vpuml.jsp) praticado justo para uma ferramenta dessa complexidade.

As opções *Open Source*, em sua maioria, orbitam em torno do [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/). As mais conhecidas são o [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/) e o [Topcased](http://www.topcased.org/). Você ainda precisará de algo para transformar os modelos em código, por exemplo o [Acceleo](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/). É nesse ponto que ferramentas como [Uml to Java Generator](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uml-java-generator) entram em cena.

Finalmente, nada te impede de usar apenas as ferramentas padrão do EMF (Ecore / Genmodel). Nesse caso eu concordo com o @utluiz, e recomendo que você baixe uma distro EMT; tenha em mente porém que a experiência é bem diferente do EclipseUML. Sem o auxílio de outros *plugins* o processo para criar os diagramas e gerar código a partir deles é razoavelmente complexo:

- Criar um projeto EMF
- Criar diagramas Encore - a experiência aqui não é tão intuitiva quanto com ferramentas CASE mais refinadas
- Criar um EMF Generator Model
- Finalmente, do modelo, gerar o código Java

Se você for tentar percorrer esse caminho recomendo o [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html) no site do [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Sei que foge um pouco do escopo da sua pergunta, que é a de encontrar um novo plugin para o Eclipse, mas eu tenho usado o Astah (antigo Jude) nos meus projetos e ele atende bem as minhas necessidades, inclusive gera o código.

De qualquer maneira, achei esse plugin: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uml-designer-eclipse-kepler-version#.Uuo3rHmRLwI .
Talvez seja útil.

Answer (score 0):

Fugindo um pouco do campo dos plugins e partindo para IDE's específicas para isso, existem ótimas ferramentes bastante profissionais e respeitadas das quais é possível fazer isso e muito mais. As mais conhecidas são o [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/) e o [Magic Draw](http://www.nomagic.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um editor/plugin Papyrus disponibilizado pelo Eclipse através do site:
[Papyrus Eclipse Update](http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/updates/index.php). Particularmente apoiando UML e outras linguagens de modelagem relacionados, tais como SysML e MARTE.

Mas você pode utilizar também sites de edição online muito completo, gera código e possui diversos diagrama com exemplos:
[UML Tool & UML Diagram](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/uml_diagram_tool)